# Title field on word document does not update immediately when saving

Tags: microsoft-word, templates, title

I have the Title document property on my document.  After I change the title, I try to save the document, but the default name doesn't reflect the new title.

[image: Title property not used as default file name]
*Title property not used as default file name*

If I cancel and save again without making any changes, then the default file name now reflects the updated title.

[image: Updated filename after cancelling original save as]
*Updated filename after cancelling original save as*

Is there a way to force the title property to update more reliably?  Is this a bug?